# Weird/Clumped up vertices topology after quad remesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, remesh

The vertices either clumps together make weird topo or it just messes the model/mesh completely, Seems like it's trying to rearrange the quads and even it out(?Maybe?) but just ends up messing up. It also happens to the other leg, But it's less obvious, I guess.

[image: This is the mesh(After sub mod)]

This is the mesh(After sub mod)

[image: This is the mesh after quad remesh(8000,face)]

This is the mesh after quad remesh(8000,face)

[image: And this one is after voxel(0.1 vert size)]

And this one is after voxel(0.1 vert size)

Comment: You won't control the result with a remesh tool, but you could try a Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide. Or maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots Yeah I can just use un-subdivide, But I want to have a smooth and even topology without exceeding 10000 tris, Cause it would be annoying for me if I ever want to go back and edit it and also making it more difficult. (Technically I can save a separate file for un sub and pre un sub, How ever I want to edit the mesh after the lowered tris.)